# It´s a correct practice to put links to questions from other forums?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, legal

Hi all, I´m usually use other manufacturer forums to search  specific information with their manufacturer tools. For instance, now I´m using System Generator that is Xilinx ise design program that works through simulink (Matlab). Af first glance I wouldn´t use this site to ask questions related with SG because Xilinx provides his own forum about this program, so I use the one Xilinx provide.
I did a easy question in that forum and I don´t get any answer so I was thinking about to ask the question in this forum (Even I know  the best forum for SG questions should be the Xilinx Forum)
I think may be, it could be interesting practice if this questions are related with other questions asked from this forum. My question could be related with other questions of this forum because it´s related with a implementation issue and this kinds of questions deal with essentials issues in the wide electronics world.

I could do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's about electronics or DSP, it fits on Electronics & Robotics. Write the entire question down instead of linking to a question in other forum, but I don't see an issue with additionally linking to show you have looked.

Comment: yes, as long as you have done research and can share it with us, the question is welcome. It is the "I haven't even looked, but.." questions that are not so welcome.

Comment: Yes,the questions are about FPGAs. You can visit: http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/DSP-Tools/Semantic-error-in-Divider/td-p/119582  http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/DSP-Tools/How-to-get-a-vector-adder-block-in-a-fast-way/td-p/119616 http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/DSP-Tools/Creating-my-own-FFT-example/td-p/119754   http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/DSP-Tools/Easy-examples-for-xilinx-blocks/td-p/119748